# listening on a window property change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, window

I am trying to listen inside a vue component to a window property change, I am not sure this is possible.
The use is for a loader, baiscally I have a file which has an interceptor which alters the "loading" property on the window object (`window.loading = true` when request initiated, `window.loading = false` when request complete (or error)) (I have issues accessing my store inside the interceptor).
The vue component looks like this:

```
<template> 
    <v-progress-linear   //this is the loader element
            height="20"
            v-show="loading"
    >
    </v-progress-linear>
    ...
    computed: { 
    loading(){
    return window.loading}
    }
```

I also tried this as a solution:

```
created () {
    window.addEventListener('loading', this.handleLoading);
  },
  destroyed () {
    window.removeEventListener('loading', this.handleLoading);
  },
  methods: {
    handleLoading(val){
      console.log(val)
    this.loading =  val
}
  },
```

The question is how can I listen on my `window.loading`

### EDIT

Here is the file which contains the interceptor code, note this does not have access to the vue instance.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { Utils } from 'em-common-vue';

import {UsersApi} from "./usersApi";
import {PartnersApi} from "./partnersApi";
import {TrialsApi} from "./trialsApi";

export function apiFactory($security) {
    const $http = axios.create({
        baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL
    });
    $http.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
        window.loading = true
        const token = $security.loginFrame.getToken();

        if (token) {
            config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
        }

        return config;

    }, function (error) {
        window.loading = true
        Utils.EventBus.$emit('toastMessageHandler', {message: error.message, type: 'error'});
        window.loading = false
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

    $http.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
        window.loading = false
        return response;

    }, function (error) {
        if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {

            Utils.EventBus.$emit('authErr', error);
        } else if (error.response && error.response.status === 403) {
            alert('You are not authorized to access this application. If you believe you are seeing this message in error, please contact support@emergingmed.com.');
        }

        else if (error.response && error.response.status !== 409){
            Utils.EventBus.$emit('toastMessageHandler', {message: error.message, type: 'error'});
        }
        else if (error.response && error.response.status === 500){
            Utils.EventBus.$emit('toastMessageHandler', {message: 'There was a problem with this operation - please contact support@emergingmed.com.', type: 'error'});
        }
        window.loading = false
        return Promise.reject({error});
    });

    const $api = {
        users: new UsersApi($http),
        partners: new PartnersApi($http),
        trials: new TrialsApi($http)
    };

    return $api;
}

// register $api as vue plugin
export function apiPluginFactory($api) {
    return {
        install(vue) {
            vue.prototype.$api = $api;
        },
    };
}
```

Here is the file which has factory function which creates the store:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

import {usersStoreFactory} from "./users/module";

// global
import {InitActions} from './actions';
import mutations from './mutations'
import getters from "./getters";

export function storeFactory($api, $config) {

    // global
    const actions  = InitActions($api);

    const store = new Vuex.Store({
        modules: {
            users: usersStoreFactory($api, $config),
        },
        state: {
            partners: null,
            // loading: window.loading
        },

        actions,
        mutations,
        getters
    });

    return store;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I really don't think communicating the loading state via `window.loading` is a good idea. Using something like the Vuex store or a similar singleton to hold the loading state seems like a much better approach but that has been (somewhat cryptically) ruled out in the question.

However, assuming that `window.loading` is the only option...

Defining a getter and setter for `window.loading` might be one way to get that approach to work. There are several ways that might be done but in my example I've chosen to proxy through to a Vue observable to hold the value.

```js
const loadingMonitor = Vue.observable({
  loading: false
})

Object.defineProperty(window, 'loading', {
  get () {
    return loadingMonitor.loading
  },
  
  set (loading) {
    loadingMonitor.loading = loading
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  computed: { 
    loading () {
      return window.loading
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    toggle () {
      window.loading = !window.loading
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ loading }}</p>
  <button @click="toggle">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

Note that `Vue.observable` was added in Vue 2.6 so if you're using an older version you'd need to use the `data` of a new Vue instance to achieve the same effect.

As the value is held in an observable object it can take part in the reactivity system just like everything else. That allows it to be used in a computed property as a reactive dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, a few questions/points:
1)I cannot use the store because of the way the app is bootstrapped, I added code above, basically everything is created with factory functions so I have no way of accessing the store from inside the interceptor file.
2)Would your solution allow to set the `window.loading` property from outside the vue component, I need to be setting it in the interceptor file?
3)Why do you say this is not recommended?
Thanks

Comment: @Michael The code I've provided would allow you to set `window.loading` from anywhere that has access to the `window` object. You would need to ensure that the getter and setter are created early, before anything tries to use them. You have various alternatives to polluting the global namespace. From a quick look through the extra code you've posted I can see two candidates. One is to use the event bus. The second is to put the loading property on `$api`. My initial impression is that your architecture is too complicated, though I obviously don't know what motivated it so I can't be sure.

Comment: really learned a lot thank you!
I am curious as to why chose to use `Object.defineProperty` as opposed to simply initializing the value by writing `window.loading = loadingMonitor.loading`?

Comment: @Michael There's nothing to keep `window.loading` in sync with `loadingMonitor.loading` if you do it that way. The initial value would be correct but then you're right back where you started with `window.loading` having a value you can't track in Vue.